# Why Mysql do not create index in subquery? How can I add index in subquery?

Tags: mysql, query-optimization, derived-table

This is my table:

```
CREATE TABLE `admin_dash_work_record` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `gameid` varchar(64) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `work_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `date` date NOT NULL,
  `watch_num` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `like_num` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `new_fans_num` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `update_time` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `areaid` varchar(64) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `average_viewer_count` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `peak_viewer_count` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `video_duration_sec` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `share_num` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `comment_num` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `expo_num` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '-1',
  `watch_seconds` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `submitted_time` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `channel_type` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `init_video_play_num` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `init_video_like_num` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `init_video_share_num` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `init_video_comment_num` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `stream_start_time` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `released_time` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `audit_status` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `streamer_task_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `uid` varchar(128) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `video_url` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `user_country` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `user_region` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `admin_task_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `applied_time` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `joined_time` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `work_id-date` (`work_id`,`date`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `idx_submitted_time` (`submitted_time`),
  KEY `idx_channel_type` (`channel_type`),
  KEY `idx_audit_status` (`audit_status`),
  KEY `idx_streamer_task_id` (`streamer_task_id`),
  KEY `idx_uid` (`uid`),
  KEY `idx_user_country` (`user_country`),
  KEY `idx_user_region` (`user_region`),
  KEY `idx_admin_task_id` (`admin_task_id`),
  KEY `idx_applied_time` (`applied_time`),
  KEY `idx_joined_time` (`joined_time`),
  KEY `idx_game_area` (`gameid`,`areaid`),
  KEY `idx_date` (`date`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2901623 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

Here are my index stats for `admin_dash_work_record`:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nvhgN.png)

| Non_unique | Key_name | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Visible |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | PRIMARY | 1 | id | A | 2445905 | YES |
| 0 | work_id-date | 1 | work_id | A | 169665 | YES |
| 0 | work_id-date | 2 | date | A | 2445905 | YES |
| 1 | idx_submitted_time | 1 | submitted_time | A | 161810 | YES |
| 1 | idx_channel_type | 1 | channel_type | A | 6 | YES |
| 1 | idx_audit_status | 1 | audit_status | A | 5 | YES |
| 1 | idx_streamer_task_id | 1 | streamer_task_id | A | 67426 | YES |
| 1 | idx_uid | 1 | uid | A | 15947 | YES |
| 1 | idx_user_country | 1 | user_country | A | 61 | YES |
| 1 | idx_user_region | 1 | user_region | A | 8 | YES |
| 1 | idx_admin_task_id | 1 | admin_task_id | A | 1953 | YES |
| 1 | idx_applied_time | 1 | applied_time | A | 51928 | YES |
| 1 | idx_joined_time | 1 | joined_time | A | 1 | YES |
| 1 | idx_game_area | 1 | gameid | A | 1 | YES |
| 1 | idx_game_area | 2 | areaid | A | 1 | YES |
| 1 | idx_date | 1 | date | A | 923 | YES |

And this is my sql：

```
 explain SELECT
  dash_work.admin_task_id,
  COUNT(distinct dash_work.streamer_task_id) AS join_num,
  SUM(dash_work.watch_num) AS watch_num,
  SUM(dash_work.like_num) AS like_num,
  ...
  dash_work.channel_type
FROM(
    SELECT
      work_id,
      ANY_VALUE(admin_task_id) AS admin_task_id,
      ANY_VALUE(streamer_task_id) AS streamer_task_id,
      ANY_VALUE(channel_type) AS channel_type,
      ANY_VALUE(video_url) AS video_url,
      SUM(watch_num) + ANY_VALUE(init_video_play_num) AS watch_num,
      SUM(like_num) + ANY_VALUE(init_video_like_num) AS like_num,
      SUM(share_num) + ANY_VALUE(init_video_share_num) AS share_num,
      SUM(comment_num) + ANY_VALUE(init_video_comment_num) AS comment_num,
      SUM(
        CASE
          WHEN date >= '2021-12-14 00:00:00' THEN watch_num
          ELSE 0
        END
      ) AS incr_watch_num,
      SUM(
        CASE
          WHEN date >= '2021-12-14 00:00:00' THEN like_num
          ELSE 0
        END
      ) AS incr_like_num,
      SUM(
        CASE
          WHEN date >= '2021-12-14 00:00:00' THEN share_num
          ELSE 0
        END
      ) AS incr_share_num,
      SUM(
        CASE
          WHEN date >= '2021-12-14 00:00:00' THEN comment_num
          ELSE 0
        END
      ) AS incr_comment_num,
      SUM(new_fans_num) as new_fans_num,
      SUM(average_viewer_count * video_duration_sec) AS average_viewer_count_sum,
      MAX(peak_viewer_count) AS peak_viewer_count,
      MAX(average_viewer_count) AS average_viewer_count,(
        case
          when ANY_VALUE(channel_type) in (1, 2, 3, 5, 6) then SUM(video_duration_sec)
          else 0
        end
      ) as video_duration_sec,(
        case
          when ANY_VALUE(channel_type) in (4, 7, 9, 8, 10) then SUM(video_duration_sec)
          else 0
        end
      ) as live_duration_sec,
      CAST(ANY_VALUE(stream_start_time) AS CHAR) AS stream_start_time,
      CAST(ANY_VALUE(released_time) AS CHAR) AS released_time
    FROM
      admin_dash_work_record force INDEX (
        `work_id-date`,
        `idx_submitted_time`,
        `idx_admin_task_id`,
        `idx_channel_type`,
        `idx_user_region`,
        `idx_game_area`
      )
    WHERE
      date <= '2023-12-19 23:59:59' AND (
        gameid = '7'
        AND areaid = 'asia'
      )
      AND (
        submitted_time BETWEEN UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2021-12-14 00:00:00')
        AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2023-12-19 23:59:59')
        AND audit_status = 1
      )
      AND channel_type in (1, 5, 6, 8, 9)
      AND user_region in (
        'Africa'
      )
    GROUP BY
      `work_id`
    ORDER BY admin_task_id, channel_type asc
  ) AS dash_work
GROUP BY
  dash_work.admin_task_id,
  dash_work.channel_type
```

And this is explain result:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q3xso.png)
When I run dash_work's build sql alone, it's fast. At that time, when external nested searches were added, it became slower.

So Why Mysql do not create index in subquery?
And How can I add index in subquery?

Maybe there are other optimization methods that have been changed, please tell me.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/subquery-optimization.html

Comment: I've added some content from my question.
AND There are 2 million pieces of data in admin_dash_work_record, and each complete query takes 30 seconds.
And when work_id is same, every column in ANY_VALUE() is same.

Comment: As previously requested - please replace the image of the explain output with the full text. How long does the subquery take to execute and how many rows does it return? Same for full query? What is the size of this table? Does it fit in the buffer pool? What are the current values of tmp_table_size and max_heap_table_size?